# Issues with toggling layers with mapbox.js

Tags: javascript, toggle, mapbox

I am having issues with toggling map layers with mapbox.js. Using the code from [https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/] it pulls the basic mapbox base maps ex. mapbox.outdoors or mapbox.satellite as toggle layers, but the polygons on the personal map layer does not appear. I know that the map can be pulled by itself, but when I try to add it to a toggling map, the polygons do not appear. I am not sure if it is a problem with the code itself that isn't allowing my personal map to show, or if there is an issue with my mapbox map.

My github repository is https://github.com/beyeraut/mappingmv/blob/gh-pages/attempt.html

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: I only see three tileLayers added in your example.`addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.outdoors'), 'Outdoors', 1);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.satellite'), 'Satellite', 2);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('silvani1.p56fej97'), '1980s', 3);` Where are the polygons you are referring to?

Comment: The polygons are on the silvan.p56fej97 layer on Mapbox. When that map is shown by itself, you can see the polygons fromm the GeoJSON file. However, when I try to add that same map to the toggle mapboxJS example, it switches background types, but the polygons no longer appear.

Comment: Can you share a link where we can see the polygons present? I think we have a confusion of tile data and vector polygon data here.